# How to get current id based on user posts

Tags: php, html, jquery, twig, drupal-8

I'm working on a Drupal custom module where users can create posts as well as edit and delete their own posts on other users' company page similar to LinkedIn. But I'm facing an issue. When I click on the edit or delete link, it does grab the dynamic id for both edit and delete, but as soon as the (Bootstrap) modal opens, the id is always 3 (Ascending order) and the data isn't the same of the specific clicked post block.

Below the is user twig template.

```
<div>
  <label for="">Your user id is {{ logged_in_user_id }}</label>
</div>#}

<div>
  {#{% for key, value in allresults %}
    <p>Name: {{ value.company_name }}</p>
    <p>Image: {{ value.post_image }}</p>
    <p>Message: {{ value.post_message }}</p>
  {% endfor %}#}
</div>

<style>
  .invalid{
    background-color: #fad4cf;
  }
  .profile_box{
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    margin-top: 20px;
    /*border-radius: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;*/
    text-align: left;
    /*width: 75%;*/
  }
  #edit{
    color: blue;
  }
  #edit:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    color: red;
  }
  .trash_icon:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .edit_post:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #txt_about{
    resize: none;
  }
</style>

<div class="profile_box">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <br />

      <div class="col-sm-4" style="width: 13%; margin-left: 2%">
        {% if page_picture == "" %}
        <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: lightgray; padding-top: 34px; padding-left: 13px">Logo Image</div>
        {% else %}
        <div><img style="height: 100px; width: 100px;" src="/sites/default/files/inline-images/company_images/{{ page_picture }}" alt="Company Image"></div>
        {% endif %}
        <br />

        {% if logged_in_user_id != 0 %}
          <div>
            <a href="{{ 'https://' in website ? website : "https://" ~ website }}" style="width: 103px;" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Visit Website</a>
          </div>
        {% endif %}
        <br />
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4" style="/*margin-left: 5%; width: 29%; color: black;*/ font-size: 22px;">
        <p><strong>{#Company Name#}{{ name_of_user }}</strong></p>
        <div><span>{#Industry#}{{ industry }}</span>,<span> {#Location#}{{ headquarters != "" ? headquarters : "location" }}</span>,<span> followers: {{ count_following }}</span></div>
        <br />
        <div><span>{#Tagline goes here#}{{ tagline }}</span></div>
      </div>

      {% if logged_in_user_id != 0 and count_following_each_other == 0 %}
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <a id="{{ logged_in_user_id != uid ? "btn_follow" : "btn_edit_page" }}" class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)">
            {{ (logged_in_user_id == uid ? "Edit Page" : "Follow+") }}</a>
        </div>
        {% elseif count_following_each_other == 1 %}
        <p><strong>Following</strong></p>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br /><br />

<!-- Menu tabs go here -->
<div style="display: flex; font-size: 22px;">
  <div>Home</div>
  <div style="margin-left: 25px;">Jobs</div>
  <div style="margin-left: 25px;">Followers</div>
  <div style="margin-left: 25px;">Members</div>
</div>

<!-- About section here -->
<div class="profile_box">
  <div class="container">
    <div style="width: 57%; font-size: 18px; margin-top: 10px;">
      <div style="float: left; margin-left: 3%;"><strong>About</strong></div>
      {% if logged_in_user_id == uid %}
      <div id="edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="float: right;">Edit</div>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr style="border-top: 5px solid #cce5f1; width: 91%;" />
  <div class="container">
    {% if about != "" %}
    <p style="width: 59%; margin-left: 2%;">{{ about }}</p>
    {% else %}
    <p style="width: 59%; margin-left: 2%;">Write something about your company page</p>
    {% endif %}
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
{% include '@company_page/user-page-edit-modal.html.twig' %}
<br /><br />
<!-- View Posts section here -->

<div>
  <p style="font-size: 20px;"><strong>View Posts</strong></p>
</div>
<br /><br />

<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between">
  <div style="font-size: 20px; margin-top: 5px;">Sort by</div>
  {% if logged_in_user_id != uid %}
    <div><button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#create_post_modal" class="btn btn-primary">Create a post</button></div>
  {% endif %}
</div>
<br /><br />
<!-- Add create post modal here -->
{% include '@company_page/create-post-modal.html.twig' %}
<br />

{% if poster_count != 0 %}

  {% for value in allresults %}

    <div class="profile_box">
<div style="margin-left: 10px;" class="">
<div class="row">
    <br />

    <div class="col-sm-3" style="width: 13%; margin-left: 2%">
      {% if page_picture == "" %}#}
      <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: lightgray; padding-top: 34px; padding-left: 13px">Logo Image</div>
      {% else %}#}
        <img height="100" width="100" class="img-responsive" src="/sites/default/files/inline-images/company_images/{{ page_picture }}" alt="Picture">
        {% endif %}
    </div>

  <div class="col-sm-9" style="/*margin-left: 5%; width: 29%; color: black;*/ font-size: 16px;">
    <!-- DISPLAY DELETE TRASH CAN ONLY TO THE OWNERS OF THE POST -->
    <div style="display: flex;">
      <p><strong>{{ value.company_name }} {{ value.poster_id }}</strong></p>
      {% if logged_in_user_id == value.poster_id %}
      <div class="edit_post" style="margin-left: 70%;" data-post-id="{{ value.id }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_post_modal">Edit Post</div>
      <!-- Edit Post Modal -->
      {% include '@company_page/post-edit-modal.html.twig' %}
      <div class="trash_icon" data-delete-id="{{ value.id }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete_post_modal"><img style="height: 25px; margin-left: 57%;" src="/sites/default/files/inline-images/posts/delete_icon.png" alt="Delete Icon"></div>
      {% include '@company_page/delete-post-modal.html.twig' %}
      {% endif %}
    </div>

    <div><span>Posted on {{ value.created_at|date("M d, Y") }}</span></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <br />

  <div class="row">
    <div class="container">
      <div style="width: 62%;" class="col-sm-9">
        {% if value.post_image != "" %}
        <div>
          <img style="margin: 0 auto;" class="img-responsive" src="/sites/default/files/inline-images/posts/{{ value.post_image }}" alt="Picture">
        </div>
        {% endif %}

        <br />
        <p style="width: 75%;">
          {{ value.post_message }}
        </p>
        <hr />
        <div style="display: flex;">
          <div>Like</div>
          <div style="margin-left: 27px;">Comment</div>
          {#{% if logged_in_user_id == poster_id %}
          <div style="margin-left: 78%;"><button id="btn_delete_post" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></div>
          {% endif %}#}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div style="background-color: lightgray; height: 65px; margin-top: 15px">
    <div class="container">
      <div style="padding-top: 24px; padding-left: 14px;">Be the first to comment on this</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
<script>

  (function ($, Drupal){
    /** Get current user id variable from above markup and pass it down here to javascript **/
    let currentUserID = '{{ logged_in_user_id }}';
    let ownerOfPageID = '{{ uid }}';
    let ownerPage = '{{ grmds_url }}';

    //let postID = $('#trash_icon').attr('data-delete-id');
    $('#btn_edit_page').on('click', function (){
      //alert("Edit page coming soon currently fixing a bug");
      //alert("You clicked the edit page button. Your user id is: " + currentUserID);
      window.location.href = "/company/"+ currentUserID +"/edit"
    });

    $('#btn_follow').on('click', function (){
      //alert("Working on the back-end logic to keep track of users being followed");
      $.ajax({
        url: "/company/" + ownerOfPageID + "/follow_user_page",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data){
          window.location.href = "/company/" + ownerPage;
        }
      });
    });

    $('#btn_submit_post').on('click', function (e){
      e.preventDefault();
      /** Validate user input fileds **/
      let post_company_name = $('#txt_name').val();
      let post_message = $('#txt_post_message').val();
      let post_image = $('#postImage')[0].files[0];

      let form_data = new FormData();
      form_data.append("postCompanyName", post_company_name);
      form_data.append("postMessage", post_message);
      form_data.append("postImage", post_image);

      //alert(post_image.name + " | " + post_image.size + " | " + post_image.type);
      if(post_company_name !== ""){
        if(post_message !== ""){
          /*if(post_image.length <= 0){*/
            /** Make Ajax request to back-end php controller **/
            $.ajax({
              url: "/company/" + ownerOfPageID + "/create_post",
              type: "POST",
              processData: false, // important
              contentType: false, // important
              data: form_data,
              dataType: "JSON",
              success: function (data){
                console.log(data);
                if(data.result === "success"){
                  window.location.href = "/company/" + ownerPage;
                } else if(data.result === "error"){
                  alert(data.msg);
                }
              }
            });
        } else {
          addClassToElements('#txt_post_message');
        }
      } else {
        addClassToElements('#txt_name');
      }
    });

    $('#btn_save_changes').on('click', function (){
      let about_text = $('#txt_about').val();
      let myFormData = new FormData();
      myFormData.append('about_text', about_text);

      /** Send to back-end and save to database **/
      $.ajax({
        url: "/company/" + currentUserID + "/edit/about",
        type: "POST",
        body: myFormData,
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data){
          console.log(data.msg);

          if(data.result === "success"){
            alert(data.msg);
            //window.location.href = "/company/" + ownerPage;
          }
        }
      });
    });

    $('.edit_post').on('click', function (){
      let edit_post_item = $(this);
      let edit_post_id = $(this).attr('data-post-id');
      alert("Edit Post id is " + edit_post_id);
    });

    $('.trash_icon').on('click', function (){
      let item = $(this);
      let id = $(this).attr('data-delete-id');
      alert("Delete Post id is: " + id);

      /** Connect to back-end database to delete selected post **/
      $('#btn_delete_post').on('click', function (){
        $.ajax({
          url: "/company/"+ id +"/delete/post",
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "JSON",
          success: function (data){
            console.log(data);
            if(data.result === "success"){
              $('#delete_post_modal').modal('hide');
              item.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();
              //window.location.href = "/company/" + ownerPage;
            }
          }
        });
      });
    });

    onBlurElements('#txt_name');
    onBlurElements('#txt_post_message');

    /** Create a function to handle all input blur elements **/
    function onBlurElements(targetElement){
      $(targetElement).blur(function (){
        //alert($(targetElement).val());
        if($(targetElement).val() === ""){
          $(targetElement).addClass('invalid');
        } else {
          $(targetElement).removeClass('invalid');
        }
      });
    }

    function addClassToElements(addClassElement){
      $(addClassElement).addClass('invalid');
    }
  })(jQuery, Drupal);
</script>
```

Below is the edit modal when the user clicks on the edit.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit_post_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit post id {{ value.id }}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <!-- Edit POST FORM -->

        <form method="post" id="post_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="edit_txt_name">Company Name</label>
            <input placeholder="Put your company name" type="text" class="form-control" name="post_company_name" id="edit_txt_name" value="{{ value.company_name }}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="">
            <label for="editImage">Upload logo image</label>

            <input name="editImage" id="editImage" style="border: 1px solid darkgray; width: 100%; border-radius: 8px;" type="file" /><br />

            <label id="popover" role="button" tabindex="0" class="" data-toggle="popover" title="Upload requirements"
                   data-content="File types allowed: .png .jpg .jpeg">? Upload requirements</label>
          </div>
          <br />
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="edit_txt_post_message">Post Message</label>
            <textarea id="edit_txt_post_message" cols="30" class="form-control" rows="10" placeholder="Post a message for {{ name_of_user }}">{{ value.post_message }}</textarea>

          </div>

        </form>
        <!-- Edit POST FORM -->

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" id="btn_submit_post" class="btn btn-primary disabled">Update</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is the controller method where the data is coming from.

```
<?php
/** Display user's page **/
public function displayUserPage($url)
{
    $db = Database::getConnection();
    $logged_in_user_in = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();

    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM {dr_user_company_page} WHERE grmds_url = :url", [':url' => $url]);
    $result = $query->fetchAll();
    $followee_id = $result[0]->uid;

    if (count($result) === 1)
    {

        $query_follow = $db->query("SELECT * FROM {dr_user_follow_page} WHERE followee_id = :followee_id", [':followee_id' => $followee_id]);
        $result_follow = $query_follow->fetchAll();

        $match_following_follower_query =$db->query("SELECT * FROM {dr_user_follow_page} WHERE (follower_id = :current_loggedin_user AND followee_id = :followee_id)",
            [':current_loggedin_user' => $logged_in_user_in, ':followee_id' => $followee_id]);
        $match_result = $match_following_follower_query->fetchAll();

        /** Check if there are any posts for the user **/
        $posts_query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM {dr_user_posts} WHERE posting_to_id = :uid", [':uid' => $followee_id]);
        $posts_result = $posts_query->fetchAll();
        return ['#theme' => 'user_page', '#logged_in_user_id' => $logged_in_user_in, '#uid' => $result[0]->uid, '#name_of_user' => $result[0]->name_of_user, '#grmds_url' => $result[0]->grmds_url, '#website' => $result[0]->website, '#industry' => $result[0]->industry, '#company_size' => $result[0]->company_size, '#company_type' => $result[0]->company_type, '#headquarters' => $result[0]->headquarters, '#founded' => $result[0]->founded, '#page_picture' => $result[0]->page_picture, '#tagline' => $result[0]->tagline, '#about' => $result[0]->about, '#postresultarray' => $result, '#count_following' => count($result_follow) , '#count_following_each_other' => count($match_result) , '#post_id' => $posts_result[0]->id, '#poster_id' => $posts_result[0]->poster_id, '#poster_count' => count($posts_result) , '#allresults' => $posts_result, ];
    }
    else
    {
        return ['#theme' => 'error_no_user_page', ];
    }
}
?>
```

I also added the php module if it helps.

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 *
 * Register a module or theme's theme implementations.
 * The implementations declared by this hook specify how a particular render array is to be rendered as HTML.
 *
 * See: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/8.2.x
 *
 * If you change this method, clear theme registry and routing table 'drush cc theme-registry' and 'drush cc router'.
 */
function company_page_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)
{
    return [
    'company_form' => ['variables' => ['name_of_user' => NULL, 'grmds_url' => NULL, 'website' => NULL, 'industry' => NULL, 'company_size' => NULL, 'company_type' => NULL, 'headquarters' => NULL, 'founded' => NULL, 'page_picture' => NULL, 'tagline' => NULL, ], ],
     'user_page' => ['variables' => ['logged_in_user_id' => NULL, 'uid' => NULL, 'name_of_user' => NULL, 'grmds_url' => NULL, 'website' => NULL, 'industry' => NULL, 'company_size' => NULL, 'company_type' => NULL, 'headquarters' => NULL, 'founded' => NULL, 'page_picture' => NULL, 'tagline' => NULL, 'postresultarray' => [], 'about' => NULL, 'count_following' => NULL, 'count_following_each_other' => NULL, 'post_id' => NULL, 'poster_id' => NULL, 'poster_count' => NULL, 'poster_company_name' => NULL, 'poster_image' => NULL, 'poster_message' => NULL, 'posted_time' => NULL, 'allresults' => [], ], ], 'error_no_user_page' => ['variables' => ['name_of_user' => NULL, ], ],
     'user_edit_page' => ['variables' => ['uid' => NULL, 'name_of_user' => NULL, 'grmds_url' => NULL, 'website' => NULL, 'industry' => NULL, 'company_size' => NULL, 'company_type' => NULL, 'headquarters' => NULL, 'founded' => NULL, 'page_picture' => NULL, 'tagline' => NULL, ],],
    ];

}
function company_page_page_attachments(array & $attachments)
{
    $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'company_page/company_page';
}
?>
```

I added images so that you can understand better as what I'm talking about. Hopefully this helps out.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I feel like I may be approaching this all wrong. Perhaps I am not making database calls properly. I am making about 3-4 database calls 1 is twice for the same table. Perhaps a join? I appreciate the help on this. Thank you!

Comment: What is the value you get in this alert on trash click alert("Delete Post id is: " + id); ?

Comment: On trash click alert the id returns 27.

Comment: Hope my answer works?

Comment: Hey man, thank you for your answer, but I have no problem with deleting. I'm having trouble displaying the id when the modal pops out... "Edit post id is 3" where it should be 27 or whatever the dynamic post id is. Also, if you noticed, the post message doesn't match with the post message in the modal. I added the "edit modal" twig template code if you wanna take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Change as below in your code.

> Step 1

Remove **#btn_delete_post** click function which is inside **.trash_icon** click.

> Step 2

Render ID into the delete button.

```
<button id="btn_delete_post" data-delete-id="{{ value.id }}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
```

> Step 3
> Get the ID from the delete button and pass it to AJAX.

```
Connect to back-end database to delete selected post **/
  $('#btn_delete_post').on('click', function (){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-delete-id');
    $.ajax({
      url: "/company/"+ id +"/delete/post",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function (data){
        console.log(data);
        if(data.result === "success"){
          $('#delete_post_modal').modal('hide');
          item.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();
          //window.location.href = "/company/" + ownerPage;
        }
      }
    });
  });
```